# laravel 5 get jobs apply users based on same table forgin key jobs_id

Tags: php, laravel

I want applicants count based on same table jobs_id(foreign key)..

```
DB::table('apply_users')
        // ->join('jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'apply_users.jobs_id')
        ->where('apply_users.jobs_id', '=', 2)
        ->get();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get the count of a certain query, use the count() function at the end instead of get(). This will automatically take the count of the query you specified.

```
DB::table('apply_users')
        // ->join('jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'apply_users.jobs_id')
        ->where('apply_users.jobs_id', '=', 2)
        ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy with count function:

```
$user_info = DB::table('apply_users')
                 ->select('id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('apply_users.jobs_id')
                 ->get();
```